# SUM sign variable php zendframefork

Tags: php, zend-framework

in my db there are two columns: sign(- or +) and value
Now i have to some all the numbers of the column value, but i have to consider the sign how can I do with this function?

```
 $select = $this->getSelect();
$option = array('SUM(u.value) as total');
 $select->from(array('u' =>         self::TABLE),$option);
```

Because with this i don't consider the sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have "VARCHAR" field type of "u.value" in your table, change it to "INT" and store integer values with "+" and "-" sign like "10, -2, 15, -5, -3".

After that try your query, or you can also try following custom query:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT SUM(u.value) as total FROM ".self::TABLE." WHERE 1");
```

Or alternatively, you cal also try following:

```
$option = array('SUM( CONVERT( CONCAT( sign, u.value ) , SIGNED INTEGER ) ) AS total');
```